# What is the mirror for installing updates?

Tags: updates, mirrors, apt-mirror

What is the mirror for installing updates? Why it is showing different no. of updates when i changed the URL in `/etc/apt/source.list` to different URL ?

Answer (score 1):

The main mirror is the "**archive.ubuntu.com**" url.
Prefixed by a country code like "**hu.archive.ubuntu.com**" means, you'll use your country's own mirror.

These own mirrors are run by individuals. That means, some of them are faster, some of them are slower. If you want the latest and greatest, with fast speed, use a different (larger) country's mirror. Like I live in Hungary, but our mirror is often outdated. So I just use the mirrors can be found in Germany, Switzerland, Austria.

Comment: But what is the role of mirror? Is it just carries the updates?

Comment: It contains _all_ the software. Updates == software. Like you have "pidgin-2.8.0-1" in Ubuntu after the install. When they release a new one, they just add the new package to the mirror with the name "pidgin-2.8.0-2". APT-GET (the package management software) will see the new version, and since the configuration says it should update, it'll get the new package and install it. That's all.

Comment: Our college has set up local mirror for ubuntu.As it is local server mirror we get the maximum speed while updates.